# How to navigate to a view controller when a specific row is selected in tableview?

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a navigation controller. Inside it i have a view controller that has a button. When the button is clicked a popover shows with a tableview of items.

When an item is selected i want to either navigate to a different view controller or open up a view controller on top of the current one.

I hope i've made my objectives clear.

Below is my current code:

private UITableView tableView;
            private List list;

```
        private class TableViewDelegate : UITableViewDelegate
        {
            private List<string> list;

            public TableViewDelegate(List<string> list)
            {
                this.list = list;
            }

            public override void RowSelected (
                UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {

               //THIS IS WHERE I AM CURRENTLY PUTTING THE NAVIGATION CONTROLLER PUSHVIEWCONTROLLER. BUT ITS NOT WORKING !!!

            }
        }

        private class TableViewDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
        {
            static NSString kCellIdentifier =
                new NSString ("MyIdentifier");
            private List<string> list;

            public TableViewDataSource (List<string> list)
            {
                this.list = list;
            }

            public override int RowsInSection (
                UITableView tableview, int section)
            {
                return list.Count;
            }

         public override UITableViewCell GetCell (
                UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                UITableViewCell cell =
                    tableView.DequeueReusableCell (
                        kCellIdentifier);
                if (cell == null)
                {
                    cell = new UITableViewCell (
                        UITableViewCellStyle.Default,
                        kCellIdentifier);
                }
                cell.TextLabel.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
                cell.TextLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 14.0f);
                cell.TextLabel.Text = list[indexPath.Row];
                return cell;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

in monotouch you should use

```
    class TableDelegate : UITableViewDelegate
        {
            public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                this.YourNavigationController.PushViewController(yourViewController,true);
            }
}
```

also i recommend you to use [monotouch.dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog)

Answer (score 1):

in your table source declare an event  like this:

```
  public class TableSourceAnimales : UITableViewSource
  {
     public  event RowSelectedEventHandler RowSelectedEvent;

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (this.RowSelectedEvent != null) {
            RowSelectedEvent (indexPath);

        }

    }

  }
```

and in your uiviewcontroller like this

```
 namespace yournamespace

 public delegate void RowSelectedEventHandler(MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexpath);

 public partial class yourclass : UIViewController
 {

 public override void ViewDidLoad ()
 {
   TableViewDataSource tablelist = new TableViewDataSource (yourlist);
   table.Source = tablelist;
   table.ReloadData ();
   table.RowSelectedEvent += tablelist_RowSelectedEvent;
 }

 public void tablelist_RowSelectedEvent (NSIndexPath indexpath)
   {
        this.YourNavigationController.PushViewController(yourViewController,true);
      //or what you want to do
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check which row is clicked in this function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And then show your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    YourViewController *vc  = [[[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in mono:

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {

                var DetailViewController = new DetailViewController ();
                // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
                controller.NavigationController.PushViewController(DetailViewController, true);
            }
```

actually its like in Obj-C only the syntax is a bit different. Try to do it yourself next time, its easy.