# Navigate from Tabbar to details

Tags: xamarin.ios

So I've created the default TabBar example in monotouch. In my case, I've replaced the two viewcontrollers content with tableviews.

Now once the end user clicks on a row, we should be able to navigate to a details page that is  not one of the tabs.

In the:

```
  public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

section I can't seem to use pushviewcontroller. Is there an example of this? I've seen the examples of showing an alert in rowselected:

```
  new UIAlertView ("Row Selected", rows [indexPath.Row].Title, null, "OK", null).Show ();
  tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
```

but I'm trying to navigate to a details page that wouldn't be one of the tabs.

Any help? I'm a newbie with Mono so any sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few other questions can help with this:

- [UITableView navigation in monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785320/uitableview-navigation-in-monotouch)
- [How to navigate to a view controller when a specific row is selected in tableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563546/how-to-navigate-to-a-view-controller-when-a-specific-row-is-selected-in-tablevie)

The MonoTouch docs also have a lot of good stuff - download and run the samples on http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/User_Interface/Tables and you will be a master in no time.

The sample in [NavItemTableSource.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/TableAndCellStyles/TableAndCellStyles/Code/NavigationTable/NavItemTableSource.cs) may be particularly useful for you.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. This was just what I needed. Two things that really helped me - 1) using the UINav controller as the rootviewcontroller and 2) using app delegate variables in the appdelegate file to be able to globally reference the viewcontrollers.

// class-level declarations
  public UITabBarController tabBarController { get; set; }
  public static AppDelegate Self { get; private set; }
  public UINavigationController MainNavController { get; private set; }